# Google Apps Custom Domain SSL configured but connection fails

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

I've followed the steps on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl and https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334. I have a custom domain, have correctly uploaded the certificate. Everything seemed to be working, but then an hour later every https: connection fails with ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED (in Chrome). How can I debug this?

- My www CNAME record is ghs.googlehosted.com
- I'm accessing the site via the www subdomain https://www.example.com
- Google Apps shows as serving SNI only for the assigned url www.example.com
- Billing is enabled
- www.example.com is set as a custom domain in cloud console
- http://www.example.com works fine
- https://app-engine-id.appspot.com works fine (but I think this is irrelevant)
- there are no errors in cloud console logs

Comment: Did you tried disabling any firewall or internet connection protection software?
Could you please check your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue but only with one app (another one works fine).

Comment: Nope, I gave up. I might try again when I have some more time. Paolo, I'll try sslabs.com if I try again, thanks.

Comment: I agree with Paolo, that the best way to resolve this problem is to use a SSL diagnostic. I had the exact problem as you and using https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/ it told me that I was missing the certificate authority. So I went back, included the CA in the public key file and it worked. This was my circumstance anyway.